# Pandas DataFrame backed by numpy memmap ndarray appears to copy data during calculations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shared-memory, numpy-memmap

I would like to have a relatively large Pandas DataFrame backed by an ndarray from memmap (from shared memory).  I have code (below) that works, however when I run a calculation on the dataframe, overall system usage (measured by top) goes up as if the process were copying over the data.  After the calculation finishes, the system memory usage goes back to baseline.  If I do the same calculation using the memmap directly, the system memory usage does not go up.  Is there a way to avoid this (apparently) temporary spike in memory usage?

(Note for both of these cases the percent memory used by the individual python process as reported by top goes up, FWIW.)

Using Pandas 0.20.3, numpy 1.13.1, python 2.7.11

Code - first script `example_setup.py`, setup the shared memory memmap:

```
import numpy

N = 7300000000  #this large N makes it really obvious on top what is happening
memmap_file = "/tmp/hello_world.bin"

progress_mod = 10000000
print N/progress_mod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "opening memmap_file:  {}".format(memmap_file)
    my_mm = numpy.memmap(memmap_file, dtype="float32", mode="w+", shape=(N,))

    print "writing to memmap file integers - N:  {}".format(N)
    for i in xrange(N):
        my_mm[i] = float(i)

        if (i%progress_mod) == 0:
            print "progress i:  {}".format(i)

    raw_input("pause here to allow other processes to use shared memory")
```

Second script `example_use.py`, use the above memmap, directly and as backing for a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import example_setup
import numpy
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    memmap_file = example_setup.memmap_file
    N = example_setup.N

    print "opening memmap_file:  {}".format(memmap_file)
    my_mm = numpy.memmap(example_setup.memmap_file, dtype="uint32", mode="r", shape=(N,))

    print "calculate mean of my_mm, monitor memory using top.  This process will show increase usage, but system usage will not increase"
    my_mean = my_mm.mean()
    print "my_mean:  {}".format(my_mean)
    raw_input("pause here before doing the above with a dataframe backed by my_mm")

    df = pandas.DataFrame(my_mm, copy=False)
    print """calculate mean of pandas DataFrame df, monitor memory using top.  Both this process and the system usage will increase.  
        When the calculation finishes, system usage will return to baseline"""
    my_df_mean = df.mean()
    print "my_df_mean:  {}".format(my_df_mean)
    raw_input("pause here before exiting")
```